# How to manipulate select query in mapinfo so that it does not high light the selected data?

Tags: cartography, mapinfo, mapbasic

I have select query in a button but I don't want user to see the way I am changing the map coordinate while selecting specific points and adding a layer. How is it possible to do that in a button ?
 Is using select query the correct way or are there other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add NOSELECT to the end of the query.

Example from the user guide:

```
Select * From World Into EarthQuery NoSelect
```

Comment: you are great :) hehe What simple answer :D

Comment: Also +1 for answer